# How to manage promises in foreach when I add item in mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try add items in the collection of mongodb.

What is the best way to resolve this whit promises in for each?

```
  putAlldata: function(items) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  MongoClient.connect(config.dbDelinquency.url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve(db);
    }
  })
}).then(function(db) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var collection = db.collection('data');

    items.forEach(function(item) {
      //console.log(item);
      db.collection('data').insert(item)
    })
    resolve(items.length);

  });
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

use Promise.all and Array.map. I asume `db.collection.insert` returns a Promise. Please let me know if it doesnt.

```
.then(function(db) {    
    return Promise.all(items.map(function(item) {
      return db.collection('data').insert(item)
    }))
    .then(() => items.length);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing `.insert` for each individual item in an array of items, you can use http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#insertMany (insertMany).

The MongoDB driver also returns promises for most methods when a callback is omitted, so you don't need to handle the promisifying yourself.

You could **rewrite all your example code** as:

```
return MongoClient.connect(url).then(db => db.collection('data').insertMany(items));
```

If you really wanted to iterate and do `.insert` individually, you could create an array of promises and use `Promise.all` to wait:

```
return Promise.all(items.map(item => db.collection('data').insert(item)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do bulk insert with `.insert` or `.insertMany`.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const collection = db.collection('data');

  try {
    const results = db.collection.insertMany(items);
    return resolve(results);
  } catch (error) {
    return reject(error);
  }
}
```

As a side note.... creating the DB connection every time you want to make a call is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You use `.map` in combination with `Promise.all` so it would be something like:

```
var promises = items.map(item => {
  return db.collection('data').insert(item)
});
Promise.all(promises).then(...etc
```

In the `.then` of the `Promise.all` you can resolve your own promise.